# ChartJs xAxis incorrect order on auto update

Tags: chart.js

when using auto update in chart.js the X Axis is not order correctly.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/wiryono/pen/BaqjXYX)

```
let dt2str = function (d, as_utc = false) {
  let Y = (as_utc === true ? d.getUTCFullYear() : d.getFullYear()).toString();
  let M = ((as_utc === true ? d.getUTCMonth() : d.getMonth()) + 1)
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, 0);
  let D = (as_utc === true ? d.getUTCDate() : d.getDate())
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, 0);
  let h = (as_utc === true ? d.getUTCHours() : d.getHours())
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, 0);
  let m = (as_utc === true ? d.getUTCMinutes() : d.getMinutes())
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, 0);
  let s = (as_utc === true ? d.getUTCSeconds() : d.getSeconds())
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, 0);
  let dstr = `${Y}-${M}-${D} ${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  return dstr;
};

let ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        yAxisID: "yAxis1",
        label: "a",
        data: [],
        borderWidth: 1,
        spanGaps: true,
        tension: 0
      },
      {
        yAxisID: "yAxis2",
        label: "b",
        data: [],
        borderWidth: 1,
        spanGaps: true,
        tension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 45
        }
      },
      yAxis1: {
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "left"
      },
      yAxis2: {
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "right",
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

setInterval(() => {
  let xtime = dt2str(new Date());
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((d) => {
    d.data.push({ x: xtime, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
  });
  chart.update();
}, 2000);
```

I check in the forum most of them is because of incorrect query return from server.
But in my example I push the data manually, which mean each new data will be the newest.

As you can see in the example the latest x tick somehow appear on the left most chart while the other has the correct order.

Also due to unable to load any chart.js plugin in the browser when not using nodejs, I use a date string for x axis.

From what I read in the API, chart.js doesn't sort the data automatically so it should mean the last push is the newest tick and should appear on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of formatting the date/time yourself, define the `x` axis as a [Time Cartesian Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) and use one of the available Chart.js [date adapters](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters).

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works with the [Luxon adapter](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon).

```js
let chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        yAxisID: "yAxis1",
        label: "a",
        data: [],
        borderWidth: 1,
        spanGaps: true,
        tension: 0
      },
      {
        yAxisID: "yAxis2",
        label: "b",
        data: [],
        borderWidth: 1,
        spanGaps: true,
        tension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
          time: {       
            unit: 'second',              
            displayFormats: {
              second: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
            },
            tooltipFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' 
        },
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 45
        }
      },
      yAxis1: {
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "left"
      },
      yAxis2: {
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "right",
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

setInterval(() => {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((d) => {
    d.data.push({ x: new Date(), y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
  });
  chart.update();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice thanks for the info. This library can be load using browser only, and script is available using npm install / cdn