Line chart not showing up in Chart.js using Laravel and PHP data
Description:
I'm working on a Laravel project where I'm trying to display a line chart using Chart.js. I'm fetching the data from my Laravel controller and passing it to the view, but the line chart is not showing up.
Issue Details:
I have a Laravel controller method (index) where I'm fetching sales data using Eloquent and passing it to the view.
In the view (admin.index.blade.php), I'm using JavaScript to initialize Chart.js and create a line chart using the sales data.
The data is fetched correctly from the controller and passed to the view using the @json directive.
However, when I load the page, only the title "Sold Projects" is displayed, and the line chart is not visible.
Code Snippets:
Controller (DashboardController.php):
public function index(){


$salesData = Sale::selectRaw('rf_date, SUM(total_production) as total_production')
    ->groupBy('rf_date')
    ->orderBy('rf_date')
    ->get();


// Extract the required data for the line chart using pluck
$dates = $salesData->pluck('rf_date');
$productionValues = $salesData->pluck('total_production');

return view('admin.index', compact('dates', 'productionValues')); }

View (admin.index.blade.php):
@extends('admin.admin_master')
@section('admin')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Sold Projects</h1>
    <canvas id="soldProjectsChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const dates = @json($dates);
        const productionValues = @json($productionValues);

        const canvas = document.getElementById('soldProjectsChart');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const salesChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Total Production',
                    data: productionValues,
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
                fill: false,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        unit: 'day'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

@endsection

Request: Could you please help me identify why the line chart is not showing up despite having the data?

Your x-scale is of type 'time' but you didn't define any date library nor date adapter. The time scale requires both, a date library and a corresponding adapter to be present.
Use one of the available Chart.js date adapters. The following answer shows how this can be done with Luxon together with chartjs-adapter-luxon.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76083987/2358409
